# Updating multiple id from array list with eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've passed to the controller an array of id and it is collected inside the student variable. I want to update the database column "lecture_id_FK" for each id in the array. I'm not sure as to how to use the array id to find the students. New in laravel.

**Controller**

```
public function setLecture($lecture,$student)
{   
    $students = student::whereIn('student_id', $student)->get();
    $students->lecture_id_FK = $lecture;
    $students->save();

    //if i type "return $student" will produce -> ai160064,ai160065
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `whereIn` method takes an [array as the second argument](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses). You can get all students by using the [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. Following getting all the records you want to update, you can do an update on all of them with the update method in laravel. With that you might be left with some code like the following:

```
public function setLecture($lecture,$student)
{   
    $studentIds = explode(',', $student);
    return student::whereIn('student_id', $studentIds)
        ->update(['lecture_id_FK' => $lecture]);
}
```

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept this answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Nice answer. @Bryan notice that when doing the `->update([..])` operation, it will return a `boolean`, not the updated students.

Comment: @HCK I think update actually will return the number of rows affected in this case, not a bool. Good note none the less.

Comment: @bryan Interesting. I didn't knew that behavior when mass-updating. It makes sense (more useful in this case). Good observation.